# Error:java: Cannot run program CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: intellij-idea

```
Error:java: Cannot run program "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java" (in directory "C:\Users\navya.chamidisetty\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\compile-server"): 
CreateProcess error=2, 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have started using IntelliJ 17 recently. When I checkout all my code in a folder and C:\ and loaded in Intellij. Now when I try to build, I am getting the above mentioned error. Could someone please help me how to solve this.

My `%JAVA_HOME% = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`

Value of Path variable in Environment variables = `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\newcorpweb\cxf\bin`

Value of Path variable in System variable = `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\`

Comment: Check the project JDK configuration, it's used for compilation, not your `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Have you checked https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/defining-a-jdk-and-a-mobile-sdk-in-intellij-idea.html? You can configure the SDK for the project or for all

Answer (score 45, accepted):

IDEA doesn't necessary use `JAVA_HOME` variable. The project SDK (JDK in your case) is setup in the project settings: File -> Project Structure, Project SDK and set up the proper path there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Open JDK by Red Hat solved my problem!
Link for the JDK
[Open JDK by Red Hat](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on NixOS with IntelliJ 2020.2. If I choose evident File -> Project structure -> SDKs -> + -> Download JDK, Idea does not see this downloaded JDK (error=2 etc.). But if I install and choose a system openjdk (located at /nix-store/...-openjdk-.../), everything works.