# IntelliJ - run program

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ.
When I try to run the Main.java I receive an error:

Error:Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\jbr\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\moran.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Can you help?

Comment: Are you suggesting it is an Intellij or system set up issue? Create a command line project from scratch, run it,

Comment: the error is simply telling you that in that directory there is not the java.exe you are calling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've downloaded, installed and configured JDK as described in [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html).

Don't use the JetBrains Runtime to build and run your own apps, you need to use a JDK.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I uninstalled my java from Program files because I need to use a java that is not an installer based. So I just followed this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290050/errorjava-cannot-run-program-createprocess-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the/48290154) and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by editing VM Options in Intellij Idea.
In Intellij go to Help -> Edit Custom VM Options, then append the below line.
`-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true`